# Is there a way to cancel a create or write operation while returning succes to the calling application?

Tags: winapi, driver, minifilter

I am trying to create a driver which fakes file writes, logging the attempts. However I do want the calling application to think it succeeded. Anybody some advice on how to do this?

I am new to driver programming (Windows); though I do have experience with C, C++ and operating system (creation).

I have looked at some samples but could not find anything like it nor was there any NTSTATUS that looks like it resembles what I am trying to do.

Edit 1:
As for the fact that i need an intermediate driver, I already knew that. Now the minispy example does the logging but doesn't do the main functionality which is faking that the operation succeeded. As for the Dokan aproach I wan't to do this myself because I find it interesting and because I want to do the same for registry keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PreWrite simply complete the operation with STATUS_SUCCESS and return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE.
The write would have done nothing, as it does not get to the Filesystem and the caller of WriteFile get a success status.

Answer (score 1):

All you really have to do to "fake" the operation is return STATUS_SUCCESS. Or in a mini-filter you would return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE from your preop routine (and set the IoStatus.Status field to STATUS_SUCCESS).

This can become more complicated when you have a process that writes some changes, and then tries to read them. If you want to completely fake this, you have to manage keeping track of all the changes without writing them to the underlying file object. This will be a very hard problem to get right for all the possible cases!

Answer (score 0):

The hard way is to build a KMDF [intermediate driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/types-of-windows-drivers). Samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/sample-kmdf-drivers), github of all samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples). Check [MiniSpy](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy), for example.

Tbe easy way is to use [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/) to create a virtual file system.

The *suggested* way is to quit the project. Windows programming is too complex for someone that hasn't developed for Windows at all, let alone KDMF developing which requires financial support.

Comment: As for the fact that i need an intermediate driver, I already knew that. Now the minispy example does the logging but doesn't do the main functionality which is faking that the operation succeeded. As for the Dokan aproach I wan't to do this myself because I find it interesting and because I want to do the same for registry keys.